# how to fix ros:Message error?

Tags: ros, mit-ros-pkg, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to run Minority Report Interface in MIT Kinect Demos, and when I rosmake kgui, I got this error:

/kgui/src/RosGlobals.h:293:21: error: ‘Message’ in namespace ‘ros’ does not name a type

and I checked RosGlobals.h, it says(start from Row 293):

```
 void Publish(const ros::Message&_msg){
      if(connected)
                    gf->publish(topic,(void*)&_msg);
    }
```

I did a little search and find this might be the difference between diamondback and electric, does anybody know how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29616/how-to-fix-ros:message-error?/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is using diamondback an option or are you looking for something more long-term.

If it is just that piece of code, you could template over the Message. That should work here. Alternately pass in a void* and change the calling code.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-03-14**:
I'm not sure how to " template over the Message". would you be more specific please? I acutally met the same problem wen try to build motion_planning_rviz_plugin in ROS electric. Would really appreciate the help here.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-03-14**:
Make the Publish function a templated function, e.g. over  and replace ros::Message with T.

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-03-19**:
Finally, I get it work! Thanks. just insert "template typename rosMessage", then replace the "ros::Message" with "rosMessage" in line 293.

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-03-19**:
It works! Thanks.